# Cloud Pub/Sub API Explorer not working

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I am new to the pubsub service and no matter what I tried in the website or java sample I couldn't make it work.
I opened this link https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects/subscriptions/create
Then turned on "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0"
Then wrote "aaa" in the `name` field and clicked on execute.
The result was as followed (the same result I got in the java App)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2.png) no-repeat}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm_2_hr.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:55px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v1beta2/aaa?key=****************;alt=json</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: this is not using dds pub sub like opensplice or anything of that nature correct?

Comment: OK, I found the issue I the name I should'nt fill "aaa" I should fill "projects/{project name}/topics/aaa"

Answer (score 1):

The name should be in the following form:

```
projects/PROJECT_ID/topics/TOPIC_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

The format in create topic in v1beta2:

name in url like: `projects/{pojectId}/topics/{your-cool-name}`

Inside the post the name have another format:

```
{
     name = '/topics/{projectId}/{your-cool-name}'
}
```